# OnConnect unwanted BLE callback during the second connection

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing a frame exchange sequence between an nRF52840 and an Android smartphone. The nRF52840 side is implemented and I am now implementing the Android application with Kotlin.

The application uses "writes" to send frames and the nRF52840 uses "notifications" to reply.

During the first connection, the frame exchange works well. However, if I disconnect and try to reconnect, the BLE device and the smartphone exchange a few frames and I receive an "onConnect" callback that crashes my application (as I am already connected).

All my operations are conditioned by a state machine, so what's my mistake?

Comment: "disconnect and try to reconnect" implies that you are not connected before reconnection...  You might be trying to _re-pair_ your devices which could possibly crash your application on second connection if you've already paired.

Comment: Further help is difficult without looking at the code

Comment: My question is mainly about the appearance of the "onConnect" callback when I am already connected, how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to solve my problem.
The frame exchange between the nRF52840 and the Android smartphone is based on a state machine. I used [D3xter's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143726/event-driven-finite-state-machine-dsl-in-kotlin) to implement this state machine and my problem seems to come from it.

So I reimplemented my state machine using [Tinder's state machine](https://github.com/Tinder/StateMachine) and [Michael Gikaru's article](https://medium.com/@thealmikey/kotlin-finite-state-machines-using-tinders-library-6554efe22272) and now it works!